# get category from word in wikipedia

Tags: wikipedia, wikipedia-api

I would like to know the category in which the word falls in.

Like it could be a place,food,clothing.. etc how do I get that from wikipedia api ? Currently I am using in this example : Pizza which is of category food .How do I get that.The following query gives me the entire page.How do I get only the category ? I really appreciate any help. Thanks in Advance.

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=categories&rvprop=content&format=xml&titles=pizza
```

response:

```
<api><warnings><main xml:space="preserve">Unrecognized parameter: 'rvprop'</main></warnings><query-continue><categories clcontinue="24768|Pizza"/></query-continue><query><normalized><n from="pizza" to="Pizza"/></normalized><pages><page pageid="24768" ns="0" title="Pizza"><categories><cl ns="14" title="Category:All articles needing additional references"/><cl ns="14" title="Category:All articles with unsourced statements"/><cl ns="14" title="Category:Articles including recorded pronunciations"/><cl ns="14" title="Category:Articles needing additional references from June 2010"/><cl ns="14" title="Category:Articles with unsourced statements from March 2013"/><cl ns="14" title="Category:Flatbreads"/><cl ns="14" title="Category:Greek inventions"/><cl ns="14" title="Category:Italian cuisine"/><cl ns="14" title="Category:Italian inventions"/><cl ns="14" title="Category:Mediterranean cuisine"/></categories></page></pages></query></api>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace `prop=revisions` with `prop=categories` and you will get a list of categories the article is in.

For example, [`api.php?action=query&prop=categories&titles=pizza`](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=categories&titles=pizza) gives you (among other things):

```
<api>
 <query>
  <pages>
   <page pageid="24768" ns="0" title="Pizza">
    <categories>
     <cl ns="14" title="Category:All articles needing additional references"/>
     <cl ns="14" title="Category:All articles with unsourced statements"/>
     <cl ns="14" title="Category:Articles including recorded pronunciations"/>
     <cl ns="14" title="Category:Articles needing additional references from June 2010"/>
     <cl ns="14" title="Category:Articles with unsourced statements from March 2013"/>
     <cl ns="14" title="Category:Flatbreads"/>
     <cl ns="14" title="Category:Greek inventions"/>
     <cl ns="14" title="Category:Italian cuisine"/>
     <cl ns="14" title="Category:Italian inventions"/>
     <cl ns="14" title="Category:Mediterranean cuisine"/>
    </categories>
   </page>
  </pages>
 </query>
</api>
```

Note that you get the *article* categories, not some kind of taxonomy of the thing the article is about. You could probably follow a 'chain' (more like a tree) of categories up to a handful of large categories that you care about. For example, the Flatbreads category leads to Breads, which leads to Foods. This means that you could assume that pizza is a food. It's no guarantee, though. Article categories are not really meant to be used that way.

If you want a better classification of 'things', instead of articles, try something like [Freebase](http://freebase.com) - which, for example, helpfully lists pizza as a kind of food. A sample query would look like this:

```
[{"id":null,"name":"Pizza","type":[{"id":null,"name":null}]}]
```

This returns, among other things, Food, Cuisine, Bread and Man-made Thing.

Comment: Currently I get the xml above as you suggested but I dont find any tag with category food .All I need is that .How do I get that .Like if I type california then it should display : place .Thats it . I really appreciate your time and effort .Thanks

Comment: Hi Wander .I would like to get an api which as I asked the question above would tell me if certain word is place,food,clothing,etc.. Which api do you think will satisfy the requirement,

Comment: Is it free api and how many calls can I make.I am looking for something which is free and can make unlimited calls per day also all I need is the category.In the above example how did you get that .Can you share the api info or any info to getting category food ?

Comment: Freebase is, as the name implies, free. The query limit is 100.000 queries per day, which should be more than enough. The example query I gave returns only the categories for every search result. Try it on freebase.com/query.

Comment: Also, you seem to think every word has only one meaning and only one category. This is by definition simply not true. If the input is "earth", do you mean the planet, dirt, or the Michael Jackson song? If the input is "casablanca", do you mean the movie or the city?

Comment: Yes I will go through every category.